# Does snappy undertstand Gauss codes?

Tags: math-software, knot-theory

The documentation says it does, but experiment says it does not. For example, this:

```
N=Manifold('Gauss: [(1,-2,3,-4),(5,-1,7,-3),(4,-5,2,-7)]')
```

Errors out. Am I being dense somehow?

Comment: Could you provide the used excerpt of the used documentation? I've checked the documentation of SnapPy version 2.8 and they can not handle Gauss notation. I've also checked the code directly on GitHub. SageMath can handle it though.

Comment: @DavidScholz The documentation seems intentionally vague, but upon legalistic reading you are right that it only guarantees Dowker-Thistlethwaite. I will look at SageMath (in actuality, what I would really like is going from a link given as an embedded PL one-manifold in $R^3$ to computing topological invariants of the complement. There is plcurve, but it seems (a) clunky and (b) only for knots. But again, I could be wrong. Could you give a pointer to the appropriate parts of SageMath? Thanks!!!

Comment: I am not an expert in this subject, so I feel like that I can't give much advice. I have just noticed that sage seems to handle gauss codes as described [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/knots/sage/knots/link.html). If this is what you really need, I don't know. SnapPy is also integrated in sage.

Comment: That's a kind of oriented PD code, not a Gauss code, right?  I haven't tested it, but this should work: `N=Manifold([(1,2,3,4),(5,1,7,3),(4,5,2,7)])`

Comment: Ok, that was incorrect.  If you have a PD code, you can do things like `N=Link([(5,1,4,2), (1,3,6,4), (3,5,2,6)]).exterior()`.  What you have is not a PD code since it's not planar -- are you able to make sure that each quadruple of indices is in counter-clockwise order?